# Mostrar producto y sus imagenes con PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla de productos y una de imagenes. Cada producto tiene mas de una imagen, pero al momento de realizar la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.nombre, producto.id_imagen, 
       imagen.id_producto_imagen, imagen.url_imagen

       FROM tabla_productos producto JOIN tabla_imagenes imagen
       ON producto.id_imagen = imagen.id_producto_imagen;
```

En PHP, al realizar el `print_r()`, me devuelve esto. Es decir, **me muestra el mismo producto por cuantas imagenes tenga**.

```
Array
    (
        [id_producto] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [nombre] => Iphone 6
        [1] => Iphone 6
        [id_imagen] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [id_producto_imagen] => 1
        [3] => 1
        [url_imagen] => P001.jpg
        [4] => P001.jpg
    )

    Array
    (
        [id_producto] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [nombre] => Iphone 6
        [1] => Iphone 6
        [id_imagen] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [id_producto_imagen] => 1
        [3] => 1
        [url_imagen] => P001_1.jpg
        [4] => P001_1.jpg
    )

    Array
    (
        [id_producto] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [nombre] => Iphone 6
        [1] => Iphone 6
        [id_imagen] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [id_producto_imagen] => 1
        [3] => 1
        [url_imagen] => P001_2.jpg
        [4] => P001_2.jpg
    )
```

Ya me rompi la cabeza al averiguar como evitarlo pero no lo logro. 
**Agradeceria mucho de su ayuda.**

Answer (score 0):

puede ser por las relaciones entre tablas productos e imágenes revisa si producto.id_imagen = imagen.id_producto_imagen tienen relación

prueba cambiando la condición en ON  ejemplo:

```
 FROM tabla_productos producto JOIN tabla_imagenes imagen
       ON producto.id_producto = imagen.id_producto_imagen;
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto

```
SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.nombre, producto.id_imagen, 
       GROUP_CONCAT('{',imagen.id_producto_imagen,',', imagen.url_imagen,'}' SEPARATOR ',') AS img

       FROM tabla_productos producto JOIN tabla_imagenes imagen
       ON producto.id_imagen = imagen.id_producto_imagen

GROUP BY producto.id_producto;
```

lo que hacemos es concatenar todas las imágenes que están relacionadas con el id del producto y hacer un objeto de estas `id_producto_imagen y url_imagen`. El resultado de esta debería de ser muy parecido a el siguiente:

```
Array
    (
        [id_producto] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [nombre] => Iphone 6
        [1] => Iphone 6
        [id_imagen] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [img] => {1,P001.jpg},{1,P001.jpg} ...
        [3] => {1,P001.jpg},{1,P001.jpg},...

    )

)
```

espero te sirva de apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puede ser un fallo en la relación de las tablas. A mi me pasaba lo mismo mucgas veces al principio. 
En estos casos optaba por crear una tabla **productos**, otra tabla **imágenes** y una tabla central que relacionaba las dos tablas con el uso de las **claves foráneas**.

De ésta manera los productos y las imágenes quedaban separadas y relacionadas. 
Por ejemplo, en la tabla central guardaba que 
*el producto X tiene las imágenes 12,15,21 y 24*
y luego, con un simple JOIN sacaba toda la información.

Encontré un Script que me ha ayudado mucho a mejorar en el diseño de mis bases de datos y a detectar errores de relación.

Puedes descargartelo desde [aqui](http://programandoamimanera.com/generador-de-consultas-sql-automatico-en-localhost/).